# (tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Cannot allocate memory) with tar, pv and tape drive

Tags: backup, tar

I'm trying to use `pv` (pipeviewer) along with tar to do tape backups in order to see the progress and eta like so:

```
du -s /home/myuser
115630916   /home/myuser
tar -cf - /home/myuser/ | pv -s 115630916 > /dev/nst0
```

Which works fine, it writes to tape successfully. But once I try and test the tar archive:

```
mt -f /dev/nst0 rewind
tar -tvf /dev/nst0
```

I get the following errors:

```
tar: /dev/nst0: Cannot read: Cannot allocate memory
tar: At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting
```

I've googled around and there have been suggestions that I use `--blocking-factor=128` when creating my backup and restoring. I still get the same error.

It's also worth noting that if I just use tar, everything works 100%, including the restore, so perhaps `pv` is breaking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it, pv was creating a different block / buffer size ...

From the **pv man** page:

> The default buffer size is the block size of the input file’s
>   filesystem multiplied by 32 (512kb  max), or 400kb if the block size
>   cannot be determined.

From the **tar man** page:

> block size of Nx512 bytes (default N=20)

So give the correct buffer size to `pv` as (20 x 512 = 10240)

```
tar -cf - /home/myuser/ | pv -B 10240 -s 142524k > /dev/nst0
```

Now if you test the archive with `tar -tvf /dev/nst0`, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error, but I wasn't using `pv` or anything else in a pipe between `tar` and the tape device.

The blocking factor bit is the key, though.  I'd read that for best results, you should use a larger block size than the default, so i had used blocking factor 512 on the tar command line:

```
tar -b 512 -cf /dev/tape files
```

Unfortunately, tar doesn't automatically figure out the blocking factor, and you need to specify it on the restore too.

```
tar -b 512 -xpf /dev/tape
```